# How to create a list of sublists in Python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
length_of_list = 3
length_of_sublists = 5

...

output = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

I tried various times but I just can't understand how to do it.

Thank you for your help guys!

Edit: I include my code as asked! It clearly doesn't work as the output is nested lists. I'm sorry if I broke some rules, I'm new here :)

```
length_of_list = 3
length_of_sublist = 5

for i in range(length_of_list):
    list = []
    for j in range(1, length_of_sublist+1):
        list.append(j)
    list.append(list)

print(list)


[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a nested list, consider using a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> length_of_list = 3
>>> length_of_sublists = 5
>>> [[i for i in range(1, length_of_sublists + 1)] for j in range(length_of_list)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you need this for, but here is your solution

```
lenght_of_list = 3
length_of_sublists = 5

output = []
for i in range(length_of_list):
    sub_list = []
    for j in range(length_of_sublists):
        sub_list.append(j+1)
    output.append(sub_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try yourself. It will definitively help you if you try out many possible approaches.
You don't need a loop for this. Just break down this one liner. You will get this.

```
>>> [list(range(1, length_of_sublists+1))] * length_of_list 
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

**Be careful when the item being repeated is a list. The list will not be cloned: all the elements will refer to the same list!**

```
>>> output[0][0] = 9
>>> output
[[9, 2, 3, 4, 5], [9, 2, 3, 4, 5], [9, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```